# How to type text using Sikuli Java Standalone jar?

Tags: java, sikuli

I am using Java Standalone APIs of Sikuli to automate my application.

I don't know how to provide/feed some text to any text-fields using this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the cursor is currently active in a text field:

```
Keyboard kb = new DesktopKeyboard();
kb.type("Hello world");
```

Or, assuming that the field accepts paste and that you don't need to simulate the individual key-presses

```
kb.paste("Hello world");
```

If you have a set of fields and tab moves between them, you can do

```
kb.paste("Hello");
kb.type(Key.TAB);
kb.paste("World");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is quite broad to answer, I'm giving you some useful links.
You can find the Java development setup basis on the [Sikuli Documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html).

Here's a more [in-depth tutorial](http://www.8bitavenue.com/2012/03/gui-testing-using-sikuli-and-java/) that also covers your exact problem, and all the available [Javadocs](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/index.html).

Just use the `type()` method on the desidered locator.

With Sikuli-api try

```
Keyboard keyboard = new DesktopKeyboard();
keyboard.type("abc");
```

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/218670

Comment: Your links refer only to the Sikuli script jar, but this question was about the [java standalone API](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) which is (at the time of writing) an incompatible rewrite of the script API.

Comment: added this reference https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/218670 , thanks for pointing the difference out.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use sikuli method type() in java program.

example:

```
 Screen screen=new Screen();
```

1st create object for screen.
then call method type() using that reference.

```
screen.type("your text");
```