# pressing Windows key using sikuli and jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

What is the value of "WINDOWS" key to be passed for the Selenium webdriver or Sikuli in keyPress method to perform an action?

I have tried to use shortcuts like WIN or Start but it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

For Sikuli you may try:

```
type(Key.ESC, KeyModifier.CTRL)
```

A bit of explanation:
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/220351
[How to type text using Sikuli Java Standalone jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196238/how-to-type-text-using-sikuli-java-standalone-jar)